# How to transform my jquery script to vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Have written parallax with jquery. 
My javascript skills are sucks.
Can you please put my code to vanilla js way.

---

https://jsfiddle.net/Islam_Ibakaev/yqb2sbgc/15/#username

```
$('#intro').on('mousemove', function(e) {
        var w = $(window).width();
        var offsetX = 0.5 - e.pageX / w;
        var moon = $(this).find('.moon');
        var buildings = $(this).find('.buildings');
        var offsetForM = parseInt(moon.data('offset'));
        var offsetForB = parseInt(buildings.data('offset'));
        var translateM = "translate(" + Math.round(offsetX * offsetForM) + "px";
        var translateB = "translate(-" + Math.round(offsetX * offsetForB) + "px";
        moon.css({
            '-webkit-transform': translateM,
            'transform': translateM,
            'moz-transform': translateM
            });
       buildings.css({
            '-webkit-transform': translateB,
            'transform': translateB,
            'moz-transform': translateB
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/8de29wgk/) what you need?

```
document.getElementById('intro').onmousemove = function(e) {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var offsetX = 0.5 - e.pageX / w;
    var moon = document.getElementsByClassName('moon')[0];
    var buildings = document.getElementsByClassName('buildings')[0];
    var offsetForM = parseInt(moon.getAttribute('data-offset'));
    var offsetForB = parseInt(buildings.getAttribute('data-offset'));
    var translateM = "translate(" + Math.round(offsetX * offsetForM) + "px";
    var translateB = "translate(-" + Math.round(offsetX * offsetForB) + "px";
    moon.style.webkitTransform = translateM;
    moon.style.MozTransform = translateM;
    moon.style.transform = translateM;
    buildings.style.webkitTransform = translateB;
    buildings.style.MozTransform = translateB;
    buildings.style.transform = translateB;
};
```

Comment: Exactly what i need! Thanks a lot man. Sorry, i cant vote it up:(